# Compute the flow of a Killing field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know that the vector field $$X = a_1\partial_1 + a_2\partial_2$$ where $a_1,a_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth,  is a Killing field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric $dx_1^2 + dx_2^2$.

I have to show that the flow of X is $$\phi_t^X(x) = A_tx+c_t$$ where $A_t$ is a rotation and $c_t$ is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: I have written a complete answer to your question, but I will post it if you show some effort. It is clearly in the continuity of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919687/solve-the-killing-equation-for-a-vector-field-in-mathbbr2-with-the-euclide) and there is in fact not so much effort to put than what in stated in my previous answer.

Comment: @Dldier is it related to the fact that $a_1, a_2$ are constants and this condition $ \partial_1a_2 = - \partial_2 a_1 $ generates a rotation ?

Comment: It is almost that, they generates a rotation + a translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919687/solve-the-killing-equation-for-a-vector-field-in-mathbbr2-with-the-euclide), I answered you that a vector field $X =a_1\partial_x + a_2 \partial_y$ is Killing in the euclidean plane if and only if
$$
\partial_x a_1 = \partial_ya_2 = 0,~ \partial_ya_1 = -\partial_x a_2
$$
By some (easy) calculations, one then shows that $X$ is Killing if and only if there exist a constant $\lambda$ and a constant vector field $V$ such that
$$
X = \lambda(y\partial_x - x\partial_y) + V
$$
It is then easy to compute the flow of $X$. Let $\gamma : t \mapsto \gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ be a smooth path. Then $\gamma$ is an integral curve of $X$ if and only if

$$\gamma'(t) = X_{\gamma(t)}$$

This leads to a linear differential equation that is easy to solve. The equation is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -\lambda\\
\lambda & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix} + V
$$

The solutions of this differential equation are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\ y(t)
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\lambda t & -\sin \lambda t \\
\sin \lambda t & \cos \lambda t
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_0 \\ y_0
\end{pmatrix} + tV
$$

Thus, $\phi_t^X (x_0,y_0) = A_t(x_0,y_0) + V_t$ where $A_t = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \lambda t & -\sin \lambda t \\
\sin \lambda t & \cos \lambda t
\end{pmatrix} $ and $V_t = tV$.
This shows that the flow of $X$ acts by isometries. More generally, one can show that in a general riemannian manifold, the flow of a Killing vector field acts by riemannian isometries. The converse is more easy to show: if the flow $\phi_t^X$ acts by isometries, then $(\phi_t^X)^*g = g$ and $L_Xg = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}((\phi^X_t)^*g) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}g=0$, and hence $X$ is Killing.

**Comment:** During the calculations, I was wondering why would it be mandatory for the rotations to have constant speed $\lambda$ and for $V$ to be constant. I mean, why would $\phi^X_t$ not have the general form
$$
\phi_t(x_0,y_0) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \lambda(t)& \sin \lambda(t) \\
\sin\lambda(t) & \cos \lambda(t)\end{pmatrix}(x_0,y_0) + V(t) 
$$
and why $\lambda$ and $V$ are forced to be linear in $t$? Indeed this general forms are isometries. But the reason is the following: for $\phi_t$ like above to be a flow, it is mandatory to have $\phi_0 = \mathrm{id}$ and $\phi_t\circ \phi_s = \phi_{t+s}$. Thus, $\lambda$ and $V$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
\lambda(0) &= 0& \lambda(t+s)&=\lambda(t) + \lambda(s) \\
V(0) &= 0& V(t+s) &= V(t)+V(s)
\end{align}
and then they have to be linear.